# Taking Derivative of Right Side of Logistic Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

I'm brushing up on calculus and started the differential equations section and found this problem and am very confused about the answer justification (not about why its **(B)**). Why does the answer not use implicit differentiation? Why is it not

$$\frac{d^2P}{dt^2}=2P'-0.004PP'?$$

I can get the same answer for $y''=0$ by factoring out $P'$ and dividing out $P'$, but it still doesn't answer why they differentiated like they did.

Also, they say their max population is $P=500$, but shouldn't max population be the limiting value of $P=1000$, with their $P=500$ instead being where it's the maximum growth rate?
[image: Book question and book answer]

From Barron's AP Calculus Premium 15th Edition

Comment: You're right, they're wrong. (Whoever "they" are; when you post pictures like this, you should cite the source.)

Comment: They probably meant to say (or type) that P=500 is the population where the maximum growth rate is seen. That part, in my opinion is a typo. To answer your first question, I think they've differentiated the first derivative with respect to $P$ and not $t$ because seeing how the rate of change of population varies with population is enough to get the right answer. I don't think it should be referred to as y'' though because y' is actually differentiated with respect to P.

Comment: You can also use quadratic completion to $P·(1000-P)=500^2-(500-P)^2$ to come to the conclusion that $P'$ is largest for $P=500$.

Comment: It looks like the solver for the problem was just a little sloppy:  the second derivative is as you calculated it, but they are looking for the value of $ \ P \ $ when that second derivative equals zero.  Since the first derivative is _not_ zero there, they divided it out of the equation.  That's fine, except apparently they didn't bother to _write the factor_ $ \ \frac{dP}{dt} \ $  in their calculation and that's how it was printed...